# How do I read a string with LINQ to XML and set an enum value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, enums

I'm using LINQ to XML/LINQ to Objects to create an object, and the object has a property that is an enum. I'm trying to figure out how to do a switch on a particular string from the XML and set the enum to a specific value.

I've listed below what I've tried so far but I just don't know the actual way to switch on attribute values. What should I do?

Example XML:

```
<post title="Title" type="newsletter">blah</post>
<post title="Another title" type="email">blah</post>
<post title="etc" type="newsletter">blah</post>
```

Example model:

```
public class PostItem
{
    public PostType PostType { get; set; }
}

public enum PostType
{
    EMail,
    Newsletter,
    Rss
}
```

And this is the actual code for constructing the models:

```
public IEnumerable<PostItem> GetPosts()
{
    var data = from postItem in xDoc.Descendants("etc etc")
               select new PostItem
               {
                   Title = (string)postItem.Attribute("title"),
                   NewsType = ?

                   //**I'm wanting to do something like this**
                   switch((string)postItem.Attribute("type")
                   {
                       case "newsletter":
                           PostType = PostType.Newsletter;

                       etc.
               };

    return data;
}
```

Comment: So, you need to write extension method which accept `XElement` as input parameter and returns `PostType`.

Comment: Question is closed so my answer went poof, but in any case, your issue is the fact that you are in an object initializer. You cannot put a `switch` statement in there. Instead, put your `switch` in a method with a parameter to switch on and then pass in your data. `PostType = ConvertToPostType(postItem.Attribute("type").Value.ToString())`